# OpenLayers2: Load markers dynamically from text file

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, geoext, markers

I am trying to load set of markers dynamically from a text file using `OpenLayers.Layer.Text`. The problem is that no markers are shown after rendering the page.

Below is the JavaScript file that is responsible for drawing the layers and loading the markers:

```
var mapPanel, tree;
function drawmap() {
var argv = drawmap.arguments;
var source=argv[0];
var target=argv[1];
var size = new OpenLayers.Size(21,25);
var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('http://www.openlayers.org/dev/img/marker.png', size,    offset);
mapPanel = new GeoExt.MapPanel({
    border: true,
    region: "center",
    map: new OpenLayers.Map({allOverlays: false}),
   center: [44.3869825, 33.3209735],
    zoom: 13,
    layers: [
             new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("BaseMap", "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
                {
                    layers: 'Layers:baselayer',
                    isBaseLayer: true,
                    visibility: true
                },
                {
                    buffer: 0,
                    visibility: false
                }
            ),
new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "Path", "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
                    {
                        transparent: 'TRUE',
                        layers: 'layers:roadlayer', 
                        viewparams: 'source:'+source+';target:'+target, 
                        isBaseLayer: false, 
                        visibility: true
                    } 
                )
   ]
});
 var textlayer= new OpenLayers.Layer.Text( "MarkersText", {   location:"./markers.txt",projection: mapPanel.map.displayProjection});
mapPanel.map.addLayer(textlayer);                                                        
var LayerNodeUI = Ext.extend(GeoExt.tree.LayerNodeUI, new GeoExt.tree.TreeNodeUIEventMixin());
 var treeConfig = new OpenLayers.Format.JSON().write([{
    nodeType: "gx_baselayercontainer"
}, {
    nodeType: "gx_overlaylayercontainer",
    expanded: true
}], true);
// create the tree with the configuration from above
tree = new Ext.tree.TreePanel({
    border: true,
    region: "west",
    title: "Layers",
    width: 200,
    split: true,
    collapsible: true,
    collapseMode: "mini",
    autoScroll: true,
    plugins: [
        new GeoExt.plugins.TreeNodeRadioButton({
            listeners: {
                "radiochange": function(node) {
                    alert(node.text + " is now the active layer.");
                }
            }
        })
    ],
    loader: new Ext.tree.TreeLoader({
        // applyLoader has to be set to false to not interfere with loaders
        // of nodes further down the tree hierarchy
        applyLoader: false,
        uiProviders: {
            "layernodeui": LayerNodeUI
        }
    }),
    root: {
        nodeType: "async",
        // the children property of an Ext.tree.AsyncTreeNode is used to
        // provide an initial set of layer nodes. We use the treeConfig
        // from above, that we created with OpenLayers.Format.JSON.write.
        children: Ext.decode(treeConfig)
    },
    listeners: {
        "radiochange": function(node){
            alert(node.layer.name + " is now the the active layer.");
        }
    },
    rootVisible: false,
    lines: false,
    bbar: [{
        text: "Show/Edit Tree Config",
        handler: function() {
            treeConfigWin.show();
            Ext.getCmp("treeconfig").setValue(treeConfig);
        }
    }]
});
// dialog for editing the tree configuration
var treeConfigWin = new Ext.Window({
    layout: "fit",
    hideBorders: true,
    closeAction: "hide",
    width: 300,
    height: 400,
    title: "Tree Configuration",
    items: [{
        xtype: "form",
        layout: "fit",
        items: [{
            id: "treeconfig",
            xtype: "textarea"
        }],
        buttons: [{
            text: "Save",
            handler: function() {
                var value = Ext.getCmp("treeconfig").getValue()
                try {
                    var root = tree.getRootNode();
                    root.attributes.children = Ext.decode(value);
                    tree.getLoader().load(root);
                } catch(e) {
                    alert("Invalid JSON");
                    return;
                }
                treeConfig = value;
                treeConfigWin.hide();
            }
        }, {
            text: "Cancel",
            handler: function() {
                treeConfigWin.hide();
            }
        }]
    }]
});
new Ext.Viewport({
    layout: "fit",
    hideBorders: true,
    items: {
        layout: "border",
        deferredRender: false,
        items: [mapPanel, tree, {
            contentEl: "desc",
            region: "east",
            bodyStyle: {"padding": "5px"},
            collapsible: true,
            collapseMode: "mini",
            split: true,
            width: 200,
            title: "Description"
        }]
    }
});
};
```

Additionally, the marker text file is:

```
lat lon title description icon
33.3253191 44.3850879 title description http://www.openlayers.org/dev/img/marker.png
```

Comment: Can you add your code on jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 2):

> Each column should be delimited by a tab space.

from http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Text-js.html

It appears yours aren't.